# Subsetting a dataframe to use with fmin yielding unexpected errors

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently using fmin() to try and fit an equation to my data. The data in the file is just a 2-column list of floats. This is my code:

```
filename = 'HAB_30_Master_Overall_no2100'
data = pd.read_csv(filename+'.csv', header=0, usecols=['Wavelength', '2.5'])

def fitFunc(x): 
    global B, A, data, sumresids
    wave = data['Wavelength']
    modelforfit = x[0]*wave**-x[1]
    data['model'] = modelforfit
    data['Residuals'] = abs(data['2.5'] - data['model'])
    sumresids = data['Residuals'].sum()
    return sumresids

def fitData():
    global xopt
    B = 2
    A = 1
    x0 = np.array([B, A])
    xopt, fopt, iter, funcalls, warnflag = fmin(fitFunc,x0,maxiter = 10000, full_output=True, disp=False) 
print xopt[0], xopt[1]

fitFunc(data['Wavelength'])
fitData()
```

And this code works when I use all the values in the file. What I'm trying to do, though, is subset the dataframe so that I can see how the fit changes when only some data points are included. If the only thing I changes is add nrows=10 to the read_csv call, even though there are >90 rows in the file, I get the error:

> ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.

And if I try doing something like making a new dataframe with .iloc to subset rows like this:

```
filename = 'HAB_30_Master_Overall_no2100'
data = pd.read_csv(filename+'.csv', header=0, usecols=['Wavelength', '2.5'])
newdata = data.iloc[:10]

def fitFunc(x): 
    global B, A, data, sumresids
    wave = newdata['Wavelength']
    modelforfit = x[0]*wave**-x[1]
    newdata['model'] = modelforfit
    newdata['Residuals'] = abs(newdata['2.5'] - newdata['model'])
    sumresids = newdata['Residuals'].sum()
    return sumresids

def fitData():
    global xopt
    B = 2
    A = 1
    x0 = np.array([B, A])
    xopt, fopt, iter, funcalls, warnflag = fmin(fitFunc,x0,maxiter = 10000, full_output=True, disp=False) 
print xopt[0], xopt[1]

fitFunc(newdata['Wavelength'])
fitData()
```

I get a warning like this:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
newdata['model'] = modelforfit
/var/folders/j8/1fzjf9cj3slcmyy1t89sth5w0000gp/T/tmpZRuvLX.py:20: 
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  newdata['Residuals'] = abs(newdata['2.5'] - newdata['model'])
```

And it crashes. Ideally I'd like to be able to use non-contiguous rows too, like the first 5 and last 5, but I'd even settle for just one chunk at a time. It would be really helpful if someone could tell me why neither of the above works and also provide a solution.

Edit: [This is a snippet of what my data looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19GLl.png) 
To get this figured out, I've just been importing one column in the read_csv call, but the end goal is to have it loop through segments of this larger file either with a subset of rows (the problem) and/or column by column (already figured out)

Comment: Can you post what your data looks like?

Comment: I edited the post above to include an image of it (not sure that's the best way? Open to suggestions if it'll help). The data imports fine with nrows used to pick out rows, it just breaks once it tries to use the functions.

Comment: Try newdata = data.iloc[:10, :] for the subsetting.